# CakePHP Project Not working after changing server

Tags: php, cakephp, web, webserver, rackspace-cloud

The Project was working , but after changing the server to a rackspace linux Server , The project Loads and when i enter username and password the page loads again to the login page and doesnt go through website . i tried to set the php.ini again but i dont know what to do any ideas ?

Comment: the server write 3 session file , it mean change session_id 3 times ? i'm not got it before , because when you access a page , there' will be only one session_id and session file created , So what can i do for server or code maybe to not change session -id , Because this bug is making my suystem not work i think right ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the database connection, .htaccess file.

You can also debug by switching the cake-debugger in core.php to 3

Also make sure your server is configured well enough to run a cakephp project. You can check this here : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks alot i will try and i will reply if it worked Or no :)